# simple html dom parser - setting dropdown value

Tags: php, parsing, dom

i'm having the following html markup:

```
<select id=gender>
    <option value=''>Please select</option>
    <option value='m'>male</option>
    <option value='f'>female</option>
</select>
```

i want to set the value using the simple html dom parser - here's my code - which doesn't work:

```
$combo = $el->find("#gender",0);
$combo->value = "m";
```

i also tried `$combo->setAttribute('value', 'm');` without success

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1):

`<select>` has no `value` attribute.  What you need to do is find the option you want selected (e.g. something like `#gender/option[value='m']`) and set the `selected` attribute on that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the selected option out of a `<select>`, you need to set `selected` on the corresponding `<option>`:

```
<select id=gender>
    <option value=''>Please select</option>
    <option value='m' selected>male</option>
    <option value='f'>female</option>
</select>
```